# Creating QGIS processing script that adds sequence to unique identifier column in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, unique-id, serial

Can anybody help me to create a QGIS processing script that adds a sequence to an existing unique identifier column (type: integer) in PostGIS?

This would be quite helpful, e.g. as a workaround for bug [#6798](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6798). Unfortunately, I do not have any Python experience.

[image]

[image]

```
CREATE SEQUENCE /*input_schema*/./*input_table*/_/*uic*/_seq OWNED BY /*input_schema*/./*input_table*/./*uic*/;
SELECT SETVAL('/*input_schema*/./*input_table*/_/*uic*/_seq', (SELECT MAX(/*uic*/) FROM /*input_schema*/./*input_table*/));
ALTER TABLE /*input_schema*/./*input_table*/
ALTER COLUMN /*uic*/ SET DEFAULT nextval('/*input_schema*/./*input_table*/_/*uic*/_seq'::regclass);
```

Comment: I would ask why in your workflow, and the workflow described in the bug, you're not managing your PostgreSQL data using PGAdmin or other core admin tools for postgresql? I don't know why there is effort spent making this work in QGIS when the admin tools do it just fine!

Comment: To me, managing tables in the QGIS DB-Manager is quite intuitive. However, I'm also interested to see how a processing script can run PostGIS queries.

Comment: For us, PGAdmin and the SQL window are more of our "GIS" than QGIS! QGIS is just the visual client to our spatial data and outputs - all the work, including 'geo'-processing, scripts, etc. are done outside of QGIS... the tools that exist to do this are already perfected, and really, the workflow of using these non-QGIS tools with PostgresSQL/PostGIS data is a better practice...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is worth noting, that python module `psycopg2` doesn't seem to automatically `COMMIT` a transaction (as other clients like QGIS DB Manager or pgAdmin do), therefore the `COMMIT` statement has to be part of the `sql` string in the script.

This does not matter with `SELECT` statements because in theses cases a `COMMIT` is obviously carried out when getting results via `cur.fetchall()`.

This is a reworked version of the script from my answer above:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#--------- define Interface
##[my_scripts]=group
##Add Serial to PostgreSQL Table=name
##Postgres_Table=vector
##Unique_identifier_column=field Postgres_Table

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import *

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *

import psycopg2

#get the parameters for the tpg table into a directory
#get the table
pg_table = processing.getObject(Postgres_Table)
#create empty dictionary for key/value pairs of the tables connection parameters
db_params = {}
db_params['uic'] = Unique_identifier_column
#iterate over connection string
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  Connection parameters')
for param in pg_table.dataProvider().dataSourceUri().split(' '):
    key_val = param.split('=')
    progress.setInfo(str(key_val))
    try:
        #set key/value pair
        db_params[key_val[0]] = key_val[1]
    except:
        pass

#generate the sql statement string
#the text in round brackets are the keys from the db_params dictionary created above
#the values belonging to the keys are inserted into the string
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  SQL statement')
sql = """CREATE SEQUENCE %(table)s_%(uic)s_seq OWNED BY %(table)s.%(uic)s;
SELECT SETVAL('%(table)s_%(uic)s_seq', (SELECT MAX(%(uic)s) FROM %(table)s)); 
ALTER TABLE %(table)s ALTER COLUMN %(uic)s SET DEFAULT nextval('%(table)s_%(uic)s_seq'::regclass);
COMMIT;""" % db_params
#remove double quotes
sql = sql.replace('"','') 
progress.setInfo(sql)

#make connection string
constr = """dbname=%(dbname)s host=%(host)s port=%(port)s user=%(user)s     password=%(password)s""" % db_params
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  DB Connection string')
progress.setInfo(constr)
#make db connection
con = psycopg2.connect(constr)
cur = con.cursor()
#execute the above created sql statement
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  Executing SQL statement ...')
cur.execute(sql)
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  ... done.')
```

Answer (score 7):

Provided your SQL statement produces valid results, the scripts below should do what you are after. Unfortunately I have nothing at hand to test this, but you could try and give feedback.

I tried to comment it for convenience, basically the script carries out three steps:

- obtain database connection parameters for the selected layer (should be postgres)
- fill the connection parameters in the sql statement string
- execute the sql statement

Note the protocol output of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#--------- define Interface
##[my_scripts]=group
##Add Serial to PostgreSQL Table=name
##Postgres_Table=vector
##Unique_identifier_column=string replace_this_with_your_uic

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import *

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *

import psycopg2

#get the parameters for the tpg table into a directory
#get the table
pg_table = processing.getObject(Postgres_Table)
#create empty dictionary for key/value pairs of the tables connection parameters
db_params = {}
db_params['uic'] = Unique_identifier_column
#iterate over connection string
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  Connection parameters')
for param in pg_table.dataProvider().dataSourceUri().split(' '):
    key_val = param.split('=')
    progress.setInfo(str(key_val))
    try:
        #set key/value pair
        db_params[key_val[0]] = key_val[1]
    except:
        pass

#generate the sql statement string
#the text in round brackets are the keys from the db_params dictionary created above
#the values belonging to the keys are inserted into the string
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  SQL statement')
sql = """CREATE SEQUENCE %(table)s_%(uic)s_seq OWNED BY %(table)s.%(uic)s;
            SELECT SETVAL(%(table)s_%(uic)s_seq, (SELECT MAX(%(uic)s) FROM %(table)s));
            ALTER TABLE %(table)s
            ALTER COLUMN %(uic)s SET DEFAULT nextval(%(table)s_%(uic)s_seq::regclass);""" % db_params
#remove double quotes
sql = sql.replace('"','') 
progress.setInfo(sql)

#make connection string
constr = """dbname=%(dbname)s host=%(host)s port=%(port)s user=%(user)s     password=%(password)s""" % db_params
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  DB Connection string')
progress.setInfo(constr)
#make db connection
con = psycopg2.connect(constr)
cur = con.cursor()
#execute the above created sql statement
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  Executing SQL statement ...')
cur.execute(sql)
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  ... done.')
```

Comment: I've tested the script and the processing log says `unexpected indent (, line 32) See log for more details`. Is there something I'm doing wrong? The SQL statement is working in the DB-Manager.

Comment: `File "C:/Users/abc/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 230, in execute
       self.processAlgorithm(progress)
     File "C:/Users/abc/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithm.py", line 298, in processAlgorithm
       exec((script), ns)
     File "<string>", line 32
       try:
      ^`

Comment: Yep, my fault. The `try` statement had wrong indentation. Just fixed this.

Comment: Thx for fixing this, but I get a Python error when running the script.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/Users/abc/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmDialog.py", line 219, in accept
       if runalg(self.alg, self):
     File "C:/Users/abc/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmExecutor.py", line 51, in runalg
       alg.execute(progress)
     File "C:/Users/abc/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 244, in execute
       unicode(e) + self.tr('\nSee log for more details'))
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 44: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Let me think about this...

Comment: Processing log:

Comment: `Algorithm Add Serial to PostgreSQL Table starting...
--------------------  Connection parameters
[u'dbname', u"'tmp'"]
[u'host', u'xxx.xxx.x.xxx']
[u'port', u'xxxx']
[u'user', u"'abc'"]
[u'password', u"'abcefg'"]
[u'sslmode', u'disable']
[u'key', u"'gid'"]
[u'table', u'"public"."test_layer"']
[u'(geom)']
[u'sql', u'']`

Comment: `--------------------  SQL statement
CREATE SEQUENCE public.test_layer_gid_seq OWNED BY public.test_layer.gid;
            SELECT SETVAL(public.test_layer_gid_seq, (SELECT MAX(gid) FROM public.test_layer));
            ALTER TABLE public.test_layer
            ALTER COLUMN gid SET DEFAULT nextval(public.test_layer_gid_seq::regclass);
--------------------  DB Connection string
dbname='tmp' host=xxx.xxx.x.xxx port=xxxx user='abc'     password='abcefg'
--------------------  Executing SQL statement ...`

Comment: And the script from the log works in db manager?

Comment: No, because it's `public.test_layer_gid_seq` instead of `'public.test_layer_gid_seq'` in line 1 and 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50391/discussion-between-eclipsed-by-the-moon-and-jochen-schwarze).

Comment: Hi Jochen, will you find some time to test/fix the script?

Comment: lots of other gis things on the heap... could you send me your recent script version to info-at-giswg-dot-de?

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a similar plugin already (although it creates a **new** unique ID field for you, rather than creating a sequence.)

This assumes you **already have a unique id field** (this doesn't need to be numeric), but want a simple numeric ID instead (1,2,3..)

In Processing toolbox, go to **Scripts > Tools > Get Scripts from Online...**

Expand "Not installed" and choose "EquivalentNumField" . Remember to click the checkbox before clicking on OK. That caught me out... ;-)

[image]

To find it quickly, type "Equiv" in the processing search bar, and you should be able to double-click it from there.

[image]

Here's an example. These woods had a unique field (osm_id) but the plugin has added a NUM_FIELD with simple numeric values instead

[image]

Comment: Steve, this is a useful script, but I'm looking for something different.

Comment: @eclipsed_by_the_moon how is this answer not what you are looking for?  It appears to ultimately solve your problem of needing a unique identifier column.